# Running a function on non empty cells

Tags: r

I have this small data set. Can you please advice on how can i move the content on **v1** to **state** column only if v1 cells are not empty? the idea is not to replace the content that is already in **state** and **zip**

```
v1    v2    state    zip
            ia     51732
nc    29576
```

Comment: By empty do you mean you have `NA` values or empty values?

Comment: i have no `NA`. Just empty values where there is no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out the rows where `v1` is not empty and move first 2 columns to column 3 and 4 for those rows. Turn first 2 columns back to empty.

```
inds <- df$v1 != ''
df[inds, 3:4] <- df[inds, 1:2]
df[inds, 1:2] <- ''

df
#  v1 v2 state   zip
#1          ia 51732
#2          nc 29576
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("", "nc"), v2 = c("", "29576"), state = c("ia", 
""), zip = c("51732", "")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```